# Ansible playbook to run SQL script against Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, ansible

We have an Azure SQL database. I'm new to ansible. How can I run a SQL script against that Azure SQL database using Ansible? I'm using Ansible 2.9

Is there any Ansible playbook that can help?

I'm trying `ms_sql` and `sqlcmd`, they all fail when running against an Azure SQL database

Comment: https://medium.com/@pavithra_38952/building-infrastructure-with-microsoft-azure-and-ansible-e5245e5b33a8
detailed example how tto build from scratch

Answer (score 0):

To execute a SQL script against an Azure SQL database using Ansible, you can use the `mssql_script` module. This module is available in Ansible 2.9 and is designed to run SQL scripts on Microsoft SQL Server, which includes Azure SQL databases.

Here's a basic example of an Ansible playbook that uses the `mssql_script` module to run a SQL script:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Run SQL script on Azure SQL Database
      mssql_script:
        db: your_database_name
        login_host: your_azure_sql_server.database.windows.net
        login_user: your_username
        login_password: your_password
        script: |
          -- Your SQL commands here
          SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

Replace `your_database_name`, `your_azure_sql_server.database.windows.net`, `your_username`, `your_password`, and the SQL commands inside the script with your actual database details and the SQL script you want to execute.

Note:

- The `mssql_script` module requires Python's `pyodbc` library. Ensure it's installed on the machine running the playbook.
- You need to provide the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of your Azure SQL Server in the `login_host` parameter.
- Ensure that the firewall rules for your Azure SQL Database allow connections from the IP address where Ansible is running.

If you're encountering issues with `ms_sql` and `sqlcmd`, it might be due to configuration or network issues. Make sure you have the correct server name, database name, login credentials, and that your network allows connections to the Azure SQL database.

If you continue to face issues, you might need to provide more specific error messages or logs to diagnose the problem further.